# activerecord equivalent of mysql date_format

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails Activerecord and have a query like:

```
MyModel.all(:select => 'date_format(created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as d')
```

This works fine with mysql, but throws an error with sqlite because the date_format function does not exist (for performance reasons we use in-memory sqlite). Is there a way to write this in pure activerecord so I'm not tied directly to mysql?

Thanks.